# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markdown' when running lektor server

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown, lektor

When running lektor server to deploy and see my website, it reports markdown is absent, while it is installed.

```
/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python3.7/site-packages/watchdog/utils/bricks.py:175: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working

  class OrderedSet(collections.MutableSet):
Traceback (most recent call last):
...

  File "/home/nick/swingrock.be/lektor/packages/tipue-content-file-generator/lektor_tipue_content_file_generator.py", line 7, in <module>
    import markdown

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markdown'
```

but markdown is installed, you can see the version here

```
nick@nick-VirtualBox:~/swingrock.be/lektor$ markdown --version

This is Markdown, version 1.0.1.
Copyright 2004 John Gruber
http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/
```

Are there any steps I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have the [Perl implementation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) of Markdown installed. However, your script appears to be expecting the [Python implementation](https://python-markdown.github.io/) and is not finding it as you do not have that implementation installed. You can install it with the following command (be sure to run the command as a user with the necessary permissions):

```
pip install markdown
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar error. With the curren version Lektor 3.1.3, I needed to downgrade `Werkzeug` to Version 0.16.

I strongly recommend **not** to do this with your system-wide installed python environment. Instead you should install a [python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

This might seem tedious now, but is worth it.

```sh
python3 -m venv ~/venv_lektor
~/venv_lektor/bin/pip install lektor
~/venv_lektor/bin/pip install Werkzeug==0.16
~/venv_lektor/bin/lektor --version
~/venv_lektor/bin/lektor quickstart --name "Test-Site"
cd ~/Test-Site/
~/venv_lektor/bin/lektor server
```